# Curl To Python Request (-d parameter)

Tags: python, rest, curl

Havin error to convert the below curl into python request.

curl -G "https://thethings.example.com/api/v3/as/applications//packages/storage/uplink_message" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" 
-H "Accept: text/event-stream" 
-d "limit=10" 
-d "after=2020-08-20T00:00:00Z" 
-d "field_mask=up.uplink_message.decoded_payload"

Python Request
`headers = {`
  `'Authorization': f'Bearer {apiKey}',`
    `'Accept': 'text/event-stream',`
`'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}`

`data = {` 
`"order": {`
       `'field_mask=up.uplink_message.decoded_payload'`
      `}`
   `}`

`response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`
`print(response.status_code)`
`print(response.text)`

Comment: Please format the code correctly, and also tell us what the error displays. Giving as much detailed info as possible is a good habit while talking about code issues, to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use this tool - https://curlconverter.com/

```
import os
import requests

API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {API_KEY}",
    'Accept': 'text/event-stream',
}

params = (
    ('limit', '10'),
    ('after', '2020-08-20T00:00:00Z'),
    ('field_mask', 'up.uplink_message.decoded_payload'),
)

response = requests.get('https://thethings.example.com/api/v3/as/applications//packages/storage/uplink_message', headers=headers, params=params)
```